# Excluding input value of reCaptcha response in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I am using reCaptcha v2 in a form for my contact page. After sending the form all the content was sent to email including the G-recaptcha-response. How can I exclude it using jquery in client - side.

This is the setup:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
 <form method="post" name="frmcontact" id="frmcontact" action="/mail/contact">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
        <td><div class="spancontacttitle">Full Name:</div>
          <div class="spancontact">
            <input type="text" class="contact" name="fullname" id="fullname" value="{{post.fullname}}" />
        </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div class="spancontacttitle">Email:</div>
            <div class="spancontact relative">
            <input type="text" class="contact" name="email_address" id="email_address" value="{{post.email_address}}" />
          </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="spancontacttitle">Your comments:</span>
          <div class="spancontact"><textarea class="textareainquiry" name="comments" id="comments">{{post.comments}}</textarea></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
             <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="{{site['recaptcha-public-key']}}" data-callback="recaptchaCallback"></div>
             <input type="hidden" class="hiddenRecaptcha required" name="hiddenRecaptcha" id="hiddenRecaptcha">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" class="submitinquiry" name="sbmt" id="sbmt" value="Send" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    function recaptchaCallback() {
        $('#hiddenRecaptcha').valid();
    };

   $("#frmcontact").validate({

    debug: true,
    ignore: ".ignore",
    submitHandler: function() {
       document.frmcontact.submit(); return true;
    },

    rules: {
        fullname: {
            required: true
        },
        email_address: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        hiddenRecaptcha: {
            required: function () {
                if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    },

    messages: {
        fullname: "This field must not be empty.",
        email_address: "Please provide a valid email address.",
        hiddenRecaptcha: "Error reCAPTCHA"
    }

});

});
</script>
```

What I have tried is disabling the hidden input upon clicking and verifying the reCaptcha:

```
hiddenRecaptcha: {
                required: function () {
                    if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
                        $('#hiddenRecaptcha').prop('disabled',false);
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        $('#hiddenRecaptcha').prop('disabled',true);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

But, still, the form is sending the reCaptcha response. What I am missing here?

Comment: I'm assuming you need the reCaptcha to validate the form?  So if you move it outside the `<form>` then the user could just bypass it.  I suspect it would be easier to add an explicit exclusion in your server code that sends the email.

Comment: Well, the problem, if I will move it outside the form, is I could not validate if the user clicked the reCaptcha button. Is there any way to validate the reCaptcha when it is outside the form just by jquery?

Comment: You can check easily enough by providing a `.submit()` handler.  But would be too easy to bypass by the user - hence the recommendation to make it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Your recaptcha will be useless without passing the `g-recaptcha-response` to the server for validation, so think about solving it on server side. But if you still want a client solution without changing your markup, here is possible way:

```
$(function() {
  $("#frmcontact").submit(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

    var arr = $(this).serializeArray();
    //concole.log(arr);
    //be sure that g-recaptcha-response is not there

    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", "/mail/contact");

    $.each(arr, function(k, v) {
      var newField = document.createElement("input");
      newField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
      newField.setAttribute("name", v["name"]);
      newField.setAttribute("value", v["value"]);

      form.appendChild(newField);
    });

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
  });
});
```

The idea is to prevent original form from submitting, then to create another form invisible for user, add all required data and submit it. 
This is also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit).